# Why is my Lucene.Net "hits" collection length returning "0"

Tags: .net, lucene.net

I've got the following method (example taken from [this link](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/09/02/lucene.net-your-first-application.aspx))

```
    Public Function ReadIndex(ByVal q As String, ByVal page As Integer?) As List(Of Domain.[Event]) Implements ILuceneService.ReadIndex
        ''# This starts us at the first record if the user doesn't have a page specified
        If page Is Nothing Then page = 0
        Dim i As Integer = page

        ''# Variables used by Lucene
        Dim reader As IndexReader = IndexReader.Open(luceneDirectory)
        Dim searcher As IndexSearcher = New IndexSearcher(reader)
        Dim query As Query = New TermQuery(New Term("fullText", q.ToLower))
        Dim hits As Hits = searcher.Search(query)

        Dim ResultIDs As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
        Dim HC = hits.Length ''# FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES
        While (i <= (page * 10) AndAlso i < hits.Length)
            Dim document As Document = hits.Doc(i)
            Dim score As Single = hits.Score(i)
            ResultIDs.Add(document.[Get]("id"))
            i += 1
        End While

        ''# Self explanitory
        searcher.Close()
        Return EventService.QueryEvents().Where(Function(e) (ResultIDs.Contains(e.ID))).ToList()
    End Function
```

But when I set a breakpoint at

```
        Dim HC = hits.Length ''# FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES
```

and analyze it in the debugger, it always says it has a length of `0` and says

> Children could not be evaluated

---

**First Screenshot**
[image]

---

**Second Screenshot**
[image]

I'm not sure what this means, however, the result of the query is always a SINGLE record being returned.  Even if I know for a fact that more than one should be returned.

---

If you'd like to read the entire service, it's posted below.

```
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Text
Imports Lucene.Net.Index
Imports Lucene.Net.Search
Imports Lucene.Net.Documents
Imports Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard
Imports Lucene.Net.Store

Namespace Domain
    Public Class LuceneService : Implements ILuceneService
        Private luceneDirectory As Directory = FSDirectory.GetDirectory(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), False)
        Private ExceptionService As Domain.IExceptionService
        Private EventService As Domain.EventService
        Sub New()
            ExceptionService = New Domain.ExceptionService(New Domain.ExceptionRepository)
            EventService = New Domain.EventService(New Domain.EventRepository)
        End Sub

        Public Function AddIndex(ByVal searchableEvent As [Event]) As Boolean Implements ILuceneService.AddIndex

            Dim builder As New StringBuilder
            builder.Append(Trim(searchableEvent.Description))
            builder.Append(" ")
            builder.Append(Trim(searchableEvent.Title))
            builder.Append(" ")
            builder.Append(Trim(searchableEvent.Location.Name))
            builder.Append(" ")
            builder.Append(Trim(searchableEvent.Region.Region))
            builder.Append(" ")
            builder.Append(Trim(searchableEvent.StartDateTime.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")))
            builder.Append(" ")
            builder.Append(Trim(searchableEvent.TicketPriceHigh.ToString))
            builder.Append(" ")
            builder.Append(Trim(searchableEvent.TicketPriceLow.ToString))
            builder.Append(" ")
            builder.Append(Trim(searchableEvent.URL))
            builder.Append(" ")
            builder.Append(Trim(searchableEvent.User.UserName))

            CreateIndex()
            Dim writer As New IndexWriter(luceneDirectory, New StandardAnalyzer(), False)

            Dim doc As Document = New Document

            doc.Add(New Field("id", searchableEvent.ID, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED))
            doc.Add(New Field("fullText", builder.ToString, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.TOKENIZED))
            doc.Add(New Field("user", searchableEvent.User.UserName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED))
            doc.Add(New Field("location", searchableEvent.Location.Name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED))
            doc.Add(New Field("date", searchableEvent.StartDateTime, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED))

            writer.AddDocument(doc)

            writer.Optimize()
            writer.Close()
            Return True

        End Function

        Public Function DeleteIndex(ByVal searchableEvent As [Event]) As Boolean Implements ILuceneService.DeleteIndex
            Throw New NotImplementedException
        End Function

        Public Function ReadIndex(ByVal q As String, ByVal page As Integer?) As List(Of Domain.[Event]) Implements ILuceneService.ReadIndex

            Dim IDList As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
            If page Is Nothing Then page = 0
            Dim i As Integer = page

            ''# Variables used by Lucene
            Dim reader As IndexReader = IndexReader.Open(luceneDirectory)
            Dim searcher As IndexSearcher = New IndexSearcher(reader)
            Dim query As Query = New TermQuery(New Term("fullText", q.ToLower))
            Dim hits As Hits = searcher.Search(query)

            Dim HC = hits.Length ''# For Debugging Purposes

            While (i <= (page * 10) AndAlso i < hits.Length())
                Dim document As Document = hits.Doc(i)
                Dim score As Single = hits.Score(i)
                IDList.Add(document.[Get]("id"))
                i += 1
            End While

            ''# Self explanitory
            searcher.Close()
            Return EventService.QueryEvents().Where(Function(e) (IDList.Contains(e.ID))).ToList()
        End Function

        Public Function UpdateIndex(ByVal searchableEvent As [Event]) As Boolean Implements ILuceneService.UpdateIndex
            Throw New NotImplementedException
        End Function

        Private Sub CreateIndex() Implements ILuceneService.CreateIndex
            If Not IndexReader.IndexExists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/")) Then
                Dim writer As New IndexWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), New StandardAnalyzer(), True)
                writer.Close()
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: What is an example value of `SearchQuery` at the point where you search?

Comment: I've edited the question to remove that line. I'm getting the same results with a simplified version of the query.

Comment: Also, I'm using Lucene.Net version 2.0.0.4 (it was the only precompiled version I could find). I'm in the process of downloading 2.4 now. I'll compile it and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears as though updating to v2.4 and editing my code has solved the problem.

```
    Public Function ReadIndex(ByVal q As String, ByVal page As Integer?) As Domain.Pocos.LuceneResults Implements ILuceneService.ReadIndex
        ''# A timer variable to determine now long the method executes for
        Dim tStart As DateTime = DateTime.Now

        ''# Creates a container that we use to store all of the result ID's
        Dim IDList As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)

        ''# First we set the initial page number. 
        ''# If it'S null, it means it's zero
        If (page Is Nothing) Or (page <= 0) Then page = 1

        ''# [i] is the variable we use to extract the appropriate (needed)
        ''# documents from the results. Its initial value is the page number
        ''# multiplied by the number of results we want to return (in our
        ''# case 10). The [last] variable is used to stop the while loop at
        ''# the 10th record by simply adding 9 to the [i] variable.
        Dim i = (page - 1) * 10
        Dim last As Integer = i + 9

        ''# Variables used by Lucene
        Dim reader As IndexReader = IndexReader.Open(luceneDirectory)
        Dim searcher As IndexSearcher = New IndexSearcher(reader)
        Dim parser As QueryParser = New QueryParser("fullText", New StandardAnalyzer())
        Dim query As Query = parser.Parse(q.ToLower)

        ''# We're using 10,000 as the maximum number of results to return
        ''# because I have a feeling that we'll never reach that full amount
        ''# anyways.  And if we do, who in their right mind is going to page
        ''# through all of the results?
        Dim topDocs As TopDocs = searcher.Search(query, Nothing, 10000)
        Dim doc As Document = Nothing

        ''# loop through the topDocs and grab the appropriate 10 results based
        ''# on the submitted page number
        While i <= last AndAlso i < topDocs.totalHits
            doc = searcher.Doc(topDocs.scoreDocs(i).doc)
            IDList.Add(doc.[Get]("id"))
            i += 1
        End While

        ''# Self explanitoryB
        searcher.Close()
        reader.Close()
        Dim EventList As List(Of Domain.Event) = EventService.QueryEvents().Where(Function(e) (IDList.Contains(e.ID))).ToList()

        Dim tStop As DateTime = DateTime.Now

        ''# Instead of just returning a list of results
        ''# I've decided to create a POCO that also contains
        ''# the number of results and how long the method took to execute.
        Dim LucienResults As New Domain.Pocos.LuceneResults With {.EventList = EventList,
                                                                  .ExecuteTime = (tStop - tStart),
                                                                  .TotalResults = topDocs.totalHits}

        Return LucienResults
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim HC = hits.Length
```

Length is a method, not a property, it should read

```
Dim HC = hits.Length()
```

Comment: yeah, unfortunately that's not it.